# A Good Solution for Drag n Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am looking into solutions for Drag N Drop of items(images, textareas, etc). I need something that will also give the coordinates of the location the item was dropped on screen, saved, and later can be placed in that exact location.

I am looking for an end result of something similar to this: https://gomockingbird.com/mockingbird/#

So far I have come up two possible solutions:

Cappuccino - http://cappuccino.org/

HTML5

What are other thoughts on either of these solutions and if they know any others that are worth taking a look at?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at jQuery --> http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#handle

Comment: +1. I've used jQuery's Draggable and Droppable to do most of what your question is asking.

Answer (score 1):

For HTML5's canvas element you can use the fantastic [kinetic](http://www.kineticjs.com/) for all your drag and drop needs. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-tutorial/) to get you started.